# Seeing units, arcsec VS cm

Tags: observational-astronomy

I am very used to working with seeing in arcseconds, but sometimes I come across the seeing in cm, e.g. [here](http://www.royac.iac.es/seeing.html).

I have looked online for a way to convert from one to the other, but I can't find any. How would this be done?

Comment: Do you have an example you could point to for seeing stated in cm? The reason I ask is because you can't specify seeing in physical distance units like cm in a general way. You could possibly do it for a specific instrument if you know that instruments [plate scale](http://panisse.lbl.gov/~sed/telescope/obsguide/platescale.html) but really that's just converting the angular size of the seeing to the physical size *for that instrument only*. I've never seen anyone do such a thing though.

Comment: Here for example: http://www.royac.iac.es/seeing.html

Comment: And I agree with what you are saying, this is why it is confusing for me. They say that the 'true' seeing which doesn't help

Answer (score 4):

Seeing is typically measured as the FWHM of the seeing disk, but can also be expressed though the [Fried parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_parameter) $r_0$, which measures the size, or strength, of the parcels of gas that cause the turbulence in the atmosphere. The relation between the two is (e.g. [Vernin & Munoz-Tunon 1995](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995PASP..107..265V))
$$
\text{seeing} = 0.98\frac{\lambda}{r_0},
$$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the light.

$r_0$ can by calculated by integrating the "turbulence strength" along the line of sight$^\dagger\!\!$, and  scales as $\lambda^{6/5}\!$. Because of this dependence, the "usual" seeing has only a weak ($\lambda^{-1/5}$) dependence on wavelength.

From [the Wikipedia article on seeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_seeing):

> At visible wavelengths, $r_0$ varies from 20 cm at the best locations to 5 cm at typical sea-level sites

---

$\dagger$<sub>Actually, $r_0$ refers to a distance corresponding to the line of sight towars zenith; observing at an angle $\zeta$ from zenith introduces a factor $\cos^{3/5}\!\zeta$.</sub>